# Возможно ли удалить сообщение пользователя в беседе для всех, с помощью чат-бота в ВК

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Вопрос. Возможно ли как-то удалить сообщения пользователя в беседе, чтобы удалилось у всех. С помощью чат-бота. На модуле `vk_api`, `longpoll`.

Comment: ну ладно, удалить нельзя. а скрыть можно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сообщение пользователя/сообщества от имени которого пишет бот, отправленное в течение последних 24 часов - да, можно. Просто вызываете штатный метод [messages.delete](https://vk.com/dev/messages.delete) с параметром delete_for_all=1:

```py
vk.messages.delete(message_ids='123,456', delete_for_all=1)
```

Сообщение какого-то другого пользователя - нет, т.к. ни API, ни интерфейс VK этого не позволяют.